# Review queue bug?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, reviewing

Today I went to review a few things as it showed that there were a few things to review in the queue, however when I clicked on the review button, there was only 1 suggested edit though the indicator which has always showed the number of suggested edits showed 5. I reviewed the edit and finished clearing the other queues and refreshed the page and it still shows 4 things to edit, but my queues are empty. Is this a bug, or something that is a result of hitting 10k rep? I haven't ever had this happen before today, and today is the first time I have reviewed anything since hitting 10k rep.

[image: review queue indicator number]

[image: empty review queues]

Comment: This is by design: there are 4 review tasks still in the queue total. You can review 0 of them because you either already have, or you skipped them.

Comment: @uni I haven't ever had this happen before today, did something change this weekend? I have reviewed many things that require multiple reviewers and have been the first reviewer and not seen this. Does 10k allow you to see how many things are in the review queue or something?

Comment: the bug itself is definitely not new, see for example http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237845/wrong-posts-number-on-review-section or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238472/review-count-fix-it-or-lose-it or this answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238699/165776

Comment: @Dragonrage I believe this is 10k behavior, yes

Comment: @uni fwiw it has now changed to 5, and I still have nothing to review. I'm not missing any new review queues or anything am I?

Comment: Have you recently suggested edits to tags?

Comment: @Robotnik no, I have not.

Comment: OK, just checking because [that's what happened to me](http://meta.arqade.com/questions/8339/i-get-notified-of-my-own-suggested-edits-for-review) a few years back.

Comment: I noticed the exact same thing at 10k. I assumed it was to alert me to more in the tools (eg. new delete votes)

Comment: Same for me at reaching 10k

Comment: Same happened at 10k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Jarrod Dixon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237873/310045),

> Review is probably our heaviest database hitter, so we've had to add
>   caching to those counts; usually it's 5 minutes on them.

So this is a status by design via [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: Bit annoying to hear.  I thought though since at 10k you can vote to delete posts, and that the number was reflective on posts that could be voted on as well.  Guess not.